# how to make gin logout function, golang jwt

Tags: go, jwt, go-gin

I have a login and authentication function with jwt, gin and golang
I can log in and maintain a session, but how do I log out? I want to perform logout from a get function

I generate the jwt token from users that are stored in my database:

generate jwt:

```
func Login(c *gin.Context) {
    var primeiroParametro models.Usuario
    err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&primeiroParametro)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "erro ao decodificar primeiroParametro para gerar JWT ": err,
        })
        log.Println("erro ao decodificar primeiroParametro para gerar JWT ", err)
        return
    }

    var segundoParametro models.Usuario
    row := DB.QueryRow(`SELECT senha, id_usuario FROM sis_usuario WHERE email = $1  OR conta = $2 OR  nome=$3`, primeiroParametro.Email, primeiroParametro.Conta, primeiroParametro.Nome)

    err = row.Scan(&segundoParametro.Senha, &segundoParametro.IDUsuario)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "erro ao escanear primeiroParametro para gerar JWT ": err,
        })
        log.Println("erro ao escanear primeiroParametro para gerar JWT ", err)
        return
    }

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(segundoParametro.Senha), []byte(primeiroParametro.Senha))
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{
            "erro": "usuário ou senha inválido",
        })
        log.Println("usuário ou senha inválido ", err)

        return

    }
    Token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
        "email": segundoParametro.Email,
        "senha": segundoParametro.Senha,
        "sub":   segundoParametro.IDUsuario,
        "exp":   time.Now().Add(time.Hour).Unix(),
    })
    err = godotenv.Load("./.env")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": "erro ao carregar arquivo .env para token ",
        })
        log.Println("erro ao carregar arquivo .env para token ", err)
        return
    }

    secret := os.Getenv("SECRET")

    TokenString, err := Token.SignedString([]byte(secret))
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "erro ao gerar token": err,
        })
        log.Println("erro ao gerar token ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "token": TokenString,
    })

}
```

I use this middleware to authenticate the routes:

middleware:

```
package middleware

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

//retornar id do usuario

func MiddlewareAutentication() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        err := godotenv.Load("./.env")
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "erro ao carregar variavel de ambiente para middleware": err,
            })
            log.Println("erro ao carregar variavel de ambiente para middleware", err)
        }

        secret := os.Getenv("SECRET")

        authHeader := c.GetHeader("Authorization")

        //tokenString := authHeader[len("Bearer "):]
        token, err := jwt.Parse(authHeader, func(t *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte(secret), nil
        })

        if err != nil || !token.Valid {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"message": "Token invalido ou expirado"})
            return
        }
        c.Next()

    }
}
```

Comment: If every call is authenticated using a JWT, then one way to log out is to add a unique ID to the JWT, and keep a list of logged out JWT ids in a database or some other store. You can clear the logged out JWT ids once the JWT expires.

Comment: What communicates with this API? If you have a frontend or another application, it would be sufficient if the other application would delete the JWT token. If this token no longer exists in the application, it can no longer attach an authorization bearer token to the request, making all calls unauthorized. Otherwise you could create an isLogedin field in the database for each user which you set to false when logging out and check in the middleware if it is false. If it is false, an unauthorized is also returned and when logging in it is set to true again and then the JTW is validated.